# Active MQ get count number of messages consumed/produced per second

Tags: activemq-classic

Is there any way in activemq with which we can get count number of messages
consumed/produced per second/minute at the broker end?

I have tried JMeter configuration using http://activemq.apache.org/jmeter-performance-tests.html but there is hardly any performance matrix I can gather.

thanks

Comment: I am trying to determine the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to write this yourself then you should use JMX on your broker.  The Broker MBean has "TotalEnqueueCount" and "TotalDequeCount" attributes.  You can poll at specific intervals for those values and calculate yourself how many messages a second/minute/hour that your broker is being produced to or consumed from.

You'll need to make sure you have JMX setup on the broker side, of course.  See here for more details on that:  http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html

Answer (score 0):

to simply view total enqueue/dequeue stats, use [jconsole](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html) or the [web console](http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html)

if you need to process it further (to calculate rates, etc), then you should do one of the following:

- access stats [programmatically using Java JMX APIs](http://www.consulting-notes.com/2010/08/monitoring-and-managing-activemq-with.html) and gather/process over time
- use a [third party tool](http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-monitor-activemq.html) for monitoring ([Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/) and [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) can also help with this)
- another option is to use [Camel Dataset](http://camel.apache.org/dataset.html) to simulate data routing and gather stats